# How to set up correct connectionstring to Oracle Database with ASP.NET / EF Core (getting ConnectionTimeout)?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I'm stuck with getting a connection to an Oracle database via Entity Framework Core running.

I created a connection via Server Explorer:

[image]

which works. I can retrieve data and run queries.

Now I have this code:

```
class InvoiceContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Invoice> invoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseOracle(@"Data Source = ODBC.dev; User Id = test; Password = test;");
        }
}
```

But every time I try something like this:

```
using (var dbc = new InvoiceContext())
{
    var inovice = new Invoice { M_IV_INVOICEAMOUNT = 20, M_IV_MANDANT = 998, M_IV_TOTALAMOUNT = 200 };
    dbc.invoices.Add(inovice);
    dbc.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get this exception:

> oracle.manageddataaccess.client.oracleexception 'connection request timed out'

I didn't find any solution via Google yet.

I have installed the odbc 18.5 drivers.

Comment: It is connection via ODBC, but oracle.manageddataaccess needs to know exact server name. [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/)

Comment: Thank you, with Using the ODP.NET without tnsnames.ora one it worked ;)